# Getting every combination of all values in multiple arrays

Tags: ruby, loops, enums, iterator

I need to test out every combination of multiple arrays, like follows:

```
%w[Y N].each do |first_indicator|
  %w[Y N].each do |second_indicator|
    %w[Y N].each do |third_indicator|
      #do stuff with first_indicator, second_indicator, third_indicator 
    end
  end
end
```

but it's obvious this is not good coding practice.

What is the "Ruby" way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you

```
a =[['Y','N'],['Y','N'],['Y','N']]
#=> [["Y", "N"], ["Y", "N"], ["Y", "N"]]
a.flatten.combination(a.size).to_a.uniq
#=> [["Y", "N", "Y"], ["Y", "N", "N"], ["Y", "Y", "N"], ["Y", "Y", "Y"], ["N", "Y", "N"],["N", "Y", "Y"], ["N", "N", "Y"], ["N", "N", "N"]]
```

Or since you have only 2 options repeated 3 times this is even cleaner

```
a = ["Y","N"]
a.repeated_permutation(3).to_a
#=> [["Y", "Y", "Y"], ["Y", "Y", "N"], ["Y", "N", "Y"], ["Y", "N", "N"], ["N", "Y", "Y"], ["N", "Y", "N"], ["N", "N", "Y"], ["N", "N", "N"]]
```

Comment: +1, I was also about to write same, but I am happy that you posted this approach.

Comment: Love the bottom solution, extremely clean and readable, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have two options, you could use the binary expansion:

```
[0..2**3-1].each do |indicator|
  first_indicator, second_indicator, third_indicator =
    (0..2).map { |i| { '0' => 'N', '1' => 'Y'}[indicator.to_s(2)[i] || '0'] }
```

Comment: I like it, Robert! Here's a variant: `(n**2).times.map {|i| ("%#{n}b" % n).tr('10 ', 'YNN').split('')}`